# How create it in Laravel Query builder

Tags: laravel, builder

SELECT e.match_id, e.team_id
FROM `matches` 
LEFT JOIN `match_events` e 
ON e.match_id = matches.id AND e.match_event_type_id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
   $result = DB::table('matches as M')
          ->leftjoin('match_events as E','E.match_id','=','M.id')
          ->where('E.match_event_type_id',1)
          ->select(['E.match_id','E.team_id'])
          ->get();
```

Comment: Nice. I was trying a way to put 2 conditions inside the leftjoin. Like a AND in the ON